# "Ищи(е)те офисы в аренду?"

Tags: орфография, глаголы, наклонение-глагола

Как правильно писать: "Ищете офисы в аренду?" или "Ищите офисы в аренду?"?

Answer (score 2):

Вообще то в вопросе была процитирована фраза с вопросительным знаком, так что ответ один - через "Е".

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от того, какой смысл вкладывается в предложение. Это у глагола повелительное наклонение, тогда будет И:
*Ищ**и**те офисы в аренду!*
Если же это вопросительное предложение, то будет Е:
*Ищете офисы в аренду?*

Answer (score 1):

В примере пишется е, потому что глагол в форме изъявительного наклонения 1 спряжения.  Форма повелительного наклонения образуется с помощью суффикса *-и*, независимо от спряжения.
"ПишИте разборчиво!" - повелительное наклонение. Если *пишЕте*, то *пишИте*. Изъявительное, повелительное.